# Wordpress get_pages meta_key don't show page

Tags: wordpress, navigation

I'm using get_pages in a Wordpress theme to create the nav.

I have some pages I don't want to show in the nav.

On all pages I have a 'dont_show_in_nav' true/false custom field.

I can use meta_key to add pages that have 'dont_show_in_nav' selected
but I'd like to not show the pages that have 'dont_show_in_nav' selected.

I could create a 'show_in_nav' custom field and select all the pages to show but I have to many pages to do that.

I've tried `'meta_value' => false`

```
    $pages_args = array(
      'sort_column' => 'menu_order',
      'parent' => 0,
      'post_type' => 'page',
      'post_status' => 'publish',
      'meta_key'  => 'dont_show_in_nav',
      'meta_value' => true
    );
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing that the issue is that `meta_value` has to be a string since WordPress only supports strings for post meta.  When you create your field, what are you actually saving?  Is it the word "true", is it a '0', a '1' etc?

Regardless, a much better method for generating nav menus in wordpress is to take advantage of the nav menu functions.  Take a look at [`wp_nav_menu()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_nav_menu), that should work much more reliably than a meta key.

Answer (score 0):

As of now Wordpress documentation for [`get_pages()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_pages) says the function doesn't support querying with a `meta_key`:

> NOTE: This function will currently not retrieve pages using the 'meta_key' and 'meta_value' parameters in the $args array as described below. Until this is fixed in the WordPress codebase, you may want to use get_posts() instead.

So your code should call [`get_posts()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_posts) instead:

```
$pages_args = array(
  'orderby' => 'menu_order',
  'parent' => 0,
  'post_type' => 'page',
  'post_status' => 'publish',
  'meta_key'  => 'dont_show_in_nav',
  'meta_value' => 'true'
);
$pages = get_posts($pages_args);
```

Note that I quoted `'true'`, since to Wordpress it's just a text field. Also, some arguments for `get_posts` are slightly different than for `get_pages`.